# Trying to run a CI server with an emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

Has anyone managed to build a stable CI server with an emulator? I've spent most of yesterday on it.
I'm using GitLab CI on a Docker container running on Core OS inside VirtualBox, inside Windows 8.1. Right now the emulator does not start and gives me no obvious message. When I try to run tests it simply tells me that there are no running devices.
My current script does this:

```
- echo yes | android update sdk -a --no-ui --filter android-22
- echo yes | android update sdk -a --no-ui --filter sys-img-armeabi-v7a-google_apis-22
- echo no | android create avd --name test -t 1 -c 1000M --abi "google_apis/armeabi-v7a" --force
- emulator -avd test -partition-size 2000 -no-skin -no-audio -no-window -force-32bit &
```

Lastly I run

```
- ./gradlew :breathcount:connectedBetaDebugAndroidTest
```

it just tells me that no devices are available, so I added something I found on SO in five minutes.

```
#!/bin/bash

adb wait-for-device

A=$(adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed | tr -d '\r')

while [ "$A" != "1" ]; do
    sleep 2
    A=$(adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed | tr -d '\r')
done

adb shell input keyevent 82
```

This just waits for 20 minutes and no device was found.
Right now I'm considering forwarding the ADB port into Docker and running the emulator directly on the machine. VMs all the way down might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait until emulator is booted up **before** running gradle script. Snippet I have been using so far:

```
- echo y | android update sdk --all --no-ui --filter "sys-img-armeabi-v7a-google_apis-23"
- echo "no" | android -v create avd --force -n arm -t "android-23" --abi "google_apis/armeabi-v7a"
- emulator64-arm -avd arm -no-audio -no-window -no-boot-anim & adb wait-for-device
- chmod +x ./gradlew
- ./gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest
```

Comment: Pretty much the same result. No devices found, segmentation fault from the enum. It might be an issue with my server.

Comment: You may need to run docker images with a privileged mode. Since it is inside of the virtual box it may not be able to access some parts of the hardware.

Comment: Try this script https://github.com/ysamlan/travis-cookbooks/blob/67635294ca3a2f883ebba308a671af1659d0e03b/ci_environment/android-sdk/files/default/android-wait-for-emulator instead of `adb wait-for-device`